# EntityFramework Employees and Tasks

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using entity framework code first and I want to have two entities: Employee and Task

I want each Task to have "CreatedBy" and "AssignedTo" employees.  This way I can get a list of all the tasks assigned to an employee, and all the tasks created by an employee.  Also in a list of tasks, I want to see who created it, and who it's assigned to.

What is the correct code first / data annotations way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
public class DBC : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int EmployeeName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Task> CreatedTasks { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Task> AssignededTasks { get; set; }

    }

    public class Task
    {
        [Key]
        public int TaskID { get; set; }

        public int AssignedToID { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee AssignedTo { get; set; }

        public int CreatedByID { get; set; }
        public virtual Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string TaskText { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You should show us what you have tried so far :)

Comment: Apologies - I'll post something asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to define your Foreign keys yourself it would look something like:

```
[ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
public int CreatedByID { get; set; }
public virtual Employee CreatedBy { get; set; }
```